# iOS tableview data lost repeat when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
let cell = self.chatTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(msgCellIdentifier) as!      ChatMsgCell
cell.nickName.text = "Li"
cell.portrait!.image = UIImage(named: "wk.png")
cell.msgContent.text = items[indexPath.row].msgContent as String
cell.bubble.image = UIImage(named: "left_bubble.png")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(edgeInsets)
cell.msgContent.scrollEnabled = false
```

This is some of my code in function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and when I set some data like 8 or 9 etc, if it's full of the screen, and it needs to scroll, and then, some data will be lost, and some data will repeat, do anyone know why ? This really bothers me a lot this days.

Comment: Can you post some screen shots showing how it is repeating the data?

Comment: i've solved this problem by nil the cell in func 'didEndDisplayingCell'~  thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the field can repeat or be lost is `msgContent`. Because the `items[indexPath.row].msgContent` can be nil. If the new value is nil, the *UITableViewCell* will **reuse** old data to display.

To solve that, use the empty string if data is nil.

```
cell.msgContent.text = (items[indexPath.row].msgContent as String) ?? ""
```

Comment: yes  your explanation is right, but i've solved this problem by nil the cell in func 'didEndDisplayingCell'~  thanks anyway :)